# MySQL how to select records of a field doesn't have all required values

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how to  select the records with a specific field doesn't cover all required values?

for example, in the following records, some students finished continuous numbered assignments, like s1 finished from 1 to 5, s4 finished from 1 to 7, but s1 and s4 had different MAX NUMBER of assignments. While some students finished NON-CONTINUOUS numbered assignments, e.g. s2 and s3. how to select the students who have finished CONTINUOUS NUMBERED assignments, regardless the max number?

[[More condition, sorry!]] I need one more column and condition to meet my real work, for example, "failed" column, where 1 means failed, 0 means passed.

Together with the original condition, I also want to exclude those students who have failed one or more assignments, that is, `failed` must be 0.

In the following records with `failed` column added, I only want to select student 1, because student 4 has failed assignment (although his assignments number are also continuous)

`id  student_id  assignment_done  failed`

`1      s1         1                0`

`2      s1         2                0`

`3      s1         3                0`

`4      s1         4                0`

`5      s1         5                0`

`6      s2         2                0`

`7      s2         4                0`

`8      s3         1                0`

`9      s3         5                0`

`10     s4         1                0`

`11     s4         2                0`

`12     s4         3                0`

`13     s4         4                0`

`14     s4         5                0`

`15     s4         6                0`

`16     s4         7                1`

Comment: can you please add your code in sql fidder or anywhere else?

Comment: What if `s2` finished `2,3,4` ? then will the final output consist of `s1,s2,s4`?

Comment: what about if any student complete assignment in random manner like 2,1,4,3,5 then also your approved ans will select that student..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT student_id, 
       COUNT(CASE failed
             WHEN '0' THEN 1
             ELSE NULL
             END) as failedCount
FROM #yourTableName(e.g, students) 
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(assignment_done) = MAX(assignment_done)
   AND
       MAX(assignment_done)=failedCount;
```

Comment: That's perfect! thank you very much! @sagivmal
BTW, how to use if instead of case? that is, something like below (but it doesn't work):
`
IF failed >= 1 THEN NULL
ELSE 1
END IF
`

Comment: It's great to hear! I think if you want using _if_ instead of case, it should be something like **COUNT(IF(failed = '0', 1, NULL)) as #failedCount**

Answer (score 1):

```
Select student_id from STUDENT group by student_id having count( assignment_done) = max(assignment_done);
+------------+
| student_id |
+------------+
| s1         |
| s4         |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: sorry @Mahesh, I changed the condition a bit, that is, s1 and S4 has different max number of assignments. Can you help further?

Comment: @Will-I-am-davidon How can we get that max number of assignments information . is it available on another table

Comment: some set of values like s1 max=5 and s4 max=7 if we can get it form some other table it will be easy

Comment: No, the max assignment number for each student is unknown, just want to know who has CONTINUOUS assignments number or who has DISCRETE assignments number

Comment: to get who haven't complete  Select student_id from STUDENT group by student_id having count( assignment_done) != max(assignment_done);

Comment: what about if any student complete assignment 1,2, 3 then also your query will not add that student..

Comment: can you please run that query and check your answer, I think it will different what you have predicted...

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way you can use below sql query

```
SELECT distinct student_id FROM Students A
WHERE A.student_id in (
    SELECT S.student_id
    FROM Students S
    GROUP BY S.student_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) =5
)
```

Comment: Not that it solves it, but at least you don't get repeats now (5 rows per student)

Comment: Hi, @Mahesh Madushanka          [  [More condition, sorry!]] I need one more column and condition to meet my real work, for example, "failed" column, where 1 means failed, 0 means passed. 

Together with the original condition, I also want to exclude those students who have failed one or more assignments, that is, `failed` must be 0.

In the following records with `failed` column added, I only want to select student 1, because student 4 has failed assignment (although his assignments number are also continuous)